# spring in harmonic motion system

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here is a spring I draw in a quiz but it is not optimized. Can you help to improve the code?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc, angles}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc, intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach\x in{-.6,-.56,..., .5} \draw[thin](\x,.23) --(\x+.1,0);
    \draw(-.65,0)--(.65,0);
    
    \begin{scriptsize}
        \def\d{2.5}
        
        \draw[decoration={aspect=0.34, segment length=1.05mm, amplitude=1.mm,coil},decorate] (.11,-.3)coordinate(X0) -- (1.4,-1.3*\d) coordinate(X1); 
        
        
        \draw(X1)--++(.1,-.3);
        
        \draw[ball color=yellow](X1)++(.068,-.17) coordinate(X2) circle(.18);
        
        \draw[dashed, thin](X2)--++(1.3, .63) coordinate(X4);
        \draw[dashed, thin](0,0)--++(1.2,.6) coordinate(X3);
        
        \draw[<->](X3)--(X4) node[midway, fill=white] {10.8 cm};
        
        \draw[dashed, red](-0,-\d-.85) ellipse(1.46 cm and .3cm);
        
        
        \draw[dashed, pink, thin](-0,-\d-.85) ellipse(1.46 cm and .3cm);
        
        \draw[<-] (0,-\d-.3) arc(88:110:2cm and 1cm);
        
        \draw(X0)--(0,0);
        \draw(0,-\d-.85)--++(-1.46,0) node[midway, fill=white] {$r$};
        
        \draw(-1.3,-2.5)node[above] {path of sphere}--++(.2,-.6);
        \draw[dashed](0,1.5)coordinate(T1)--(0,-2);
        
        \coordinate(T0) at(0,0);
        \coordinate(T2) at(-.42,.95);
        
        \draw(T1)--(T0)--(T2)pic[draw=blue,->,angle eccentricity=1,angle radius=.75cm] {angle=T1--T0--T2};
        
        \path(T0)--++(-.25,1.3) node{$27^\circ$};       
        
        
    \end{scriptsize}
    
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What don't you like about your code?

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions.

1. I removed duplicates from the preamble
2. I moved long style statements to the beginning. This makes the following code more readble, and even if you use each style only once, it's nicer to perform changes just here, and only here.
3. It's a good attitude to document code. At least I will have forgotten all the details next time I reuse the code ...
4. I don't see much value in introducing `\pic`s as a kind of standardization: there hardly are elements being used twice. However, I suggest to change their order to a more logical one, like first the drawings, finally the labels. As it is now, it's quite intermingled. I'd try finding better groupings of code.
5. The angle `27deg` might be such a target for refactoring: not only do you mark it at the top, but it also affects the spring and the ball. Which would suggest using some polar coordinates instead, like `(27:5cm)`.
6. I also started to reformat some lines, to make differences more self-evident at a glance. That's quite related to personal preferences. However, if done correctly, errors are easier to spot, to prevent and to correct.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc, angles}
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc, intersections} % duplicates
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}[% refactoring styles here
        dt/.style={dashed, thin,teal},
        angl/.style={draw=blue,->,angle eccentricity=1,angle radius=.75cm},
        spring/.style={decoration={
                                    aspect=0.34, 
                                    segment length=1.05mm, 
                                    amplitude=1.mm,
                                    coil}
                        ,decorate},
        bll/.style={ball color=yellow},
    ]
    % ~~~ hatches ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \foreach\x in{-.6,-.56,..., .5} \draw[thin](\x,.23) --(\x+.1,0);
    \draw(-.65,0)--(.65,0);
    
    \begin{scriptsize}
        \def\d{2.5}
        
        % ~~~ spring ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \draw[spring] (.11,-.3) coordinate(X0) -- (1.4,-1.3*\d) coordinate(X1); 
 
        % ??
        \draw (X1) -- ++(.1,-.3);
        
        % ~~~ ball ~~~~~
        \draw[bll] (X1) ++ (.068,-.17) coordinate(X2) circle(.18);
        
        % ~~~ for the spring dimensions ~~~~~
        \draw[dt](X2)  -- ++(1.3, .63) coordinate(X4);
        \draw[dt](0,0) -- ++(1.2, .6 ) coordinate(X3);
        
        \draw[<->](X3)--(X4) node[midway, fill=white] {10.8 cm};
        
        % ~~~ region, where the ball will move ~~~~~~~~~~~
        \draw[dashed, red]  (-0,-\d-.85) ellipse(1.46 cm and .3cm);        
        \draw[dt,pink]      (-0,-\d-.85) ellipse(1.46 cm and .3cm);
        
        % ~~~ the curved arrow (certainly with a purpose) ~~~~~~~~~
        \draw[<-] (0,-\d-.3) arc(88:110:2cm and 1cm);
        
        \draw(X0)--(0,0);
        \draw(0,-\d-.85)--++(-1.46,0) node[midway, fill=white] {$r$};
        
        \draw           (-1.3,-2.5) node[above] {path of sphere}--++(.2,-.6);
        \draw[dashed]   (   0, 1.5) coordinate(T1) -- (0,-2);
        
        \coordinate(T0) at(0,0);
        \coordinate(T2) at(-.42,.95);
        
        \draw(T1)--(T0)--(T2)pic[angl] {angle=T1--T0--T2};
        
        \path(T0)--++(-.25,1.3) node{$27^\circ$};       
    \end{scriptsize}
    
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: the O(0,0), (T2), and the ball are NOT on the same line. We are not sure of the two dashes are perpendicular to the line O, T2.

Comment: Ok. Again, things become easier when using polar coordinates here: 27deg, 117deg, -27deg and 63deg should be all you need. Also there's a perpendicular feature. Also the ends at the coil are not needed: use pre lenght and post length instead. See http://tikz.dev .